# Unable to ssh into Azure VM -- connection timed out

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create a VM with the Azure CLI and `ssh` into it from Azure Cloud Shell. I have followed the official guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-cli) by running these commands:

```
$ az group create --name myGroupName --location westus2
$ az vm create --resource-group myGroupName --name myVmName --image UbuntuLTS --admin-username azureuser --generate-ssh-keys
```

However, when try to connect via `ssh` with the public IP address reported by the second command above, the connection times out:

```
$ ssh -vvv azureuser@publicIpAddress
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "publicIpAddress" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to publicIpAddress [publicIpAddress] port 22.
debug1: connect to address publicIpAddress port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host publicIpAddress  port 22: Connection timed out
```

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

In addition, I have tried running these commands in Powershell on my local machine. I have found that after I create a new resource group, and then launch a VM, I am able to `ssh` into the VM using Powershell. But when I disconnect from the VM and then try to `ssh` back into it, I am unable to re-connect since it results in the timeout error. If I try to create a new VM under the same resource group, I am unable to `ssh` into it at all. If instead, I create a new resource group and a new VM, I can `ssh` into it the first time, but not on subsequent tries.

Comment: `ssh -vvv azureuser@publicIpAddress` - did you fill your actual public IP address here? From the log messages it seems like you did not do this step.

Comment: Yes, I used the actual public IP address, and simply replaced it with "publicIpAddress" to post it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, you could check if there is an NSG automatically associated with your VM NIC or subnet by Azure policy or others in your current subscription after you create the Azure VM. Probably, it adds some inbound port rules in the NSG to blocking the network connection. If you want to SSH into your Azure VM. it must have a higher priority inbound rule to allow access port 22 as below. You also could add your client public IP as the **source** in the rule to narrow the limitation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nancy Xiong. You are correct that my subscription adds some inbound port rules to the NSG to block SSH connections. This seems to happen within 1-2 minutes from the creation of the VM. When I modify those rules to allow for SSH from my source IP, the NSG automatically restores the rules to the previous settings. So I think it may be impossible to modify them permanently due to the Azure policy on my subscription.

Comment: To automatically locate the problematic rules: try testing your connection in the azure portal

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCt97.png

It points you to the exact inbound rules inside Networking tab which might be blocking your connections.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it solves the problem reset the SSH configuration in Reset password > Reset only configuration > Update button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try testing your connection in the azure portal

[image]

It points you to the exact inbound rules inside Networking tab which might be blocking your connections.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that I had lost my connection due to a change of NIC:s in my VM, so if this is the case for you too you should take a look at that and disassociate the old public ip address (connected to your old nic) and associate it again but with the new nic. Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above steps, You might want to start the OpenSSH SSH Server service manually from Windows Services.

Services.exe -> OpenSSH SSH Server -> Start the service and set the startup type from Manual to Automatic.